# chrome not working with jquery remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Can anyone explain why this jsfiddle does not work in chrome, but works flawlessly in Firefox?

here's the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bu33n/

Here's the code just in case jsfiddle is inaccesible:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="scheduleSet" id="remove19s">
        <p>I am a schedule19</p>
    </div>
    <div class="scheduleSet" id="remove5s">
        <p>I am a schedule5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="phoneSet" id="remove19p">
        <p>I am a phone19</p>
    </div>
    <div class="phoneSet" id="remove5p">
        <p>I am a phone5</p>
    </div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Location.removeMe('remove19p');">Remove me</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Location.addMe();">Add me</a>

</div>
```

JS:

```
Location.removeMe = function (data) {
    var stuff = "";
    stuff = data;
    $('div').remove('#' + stuff);
    return false;
};

Location.addMe = function () {
    $('.container').append("<div class='phoneSet' id='remove19p'>" +
        "<p>I am a replacement phone19</p>" +
        "</div>");
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `$('#' + stuff).remove()`? For that matter why do you even have the `stuff` variable when you can just say `'#' + data`? (And note that there's no point initialising `stuff` to an empty string when you immediately set it to something else on the next line.)

Comment: @nnnnnn i was under the impression it had to be done this way via the jquery documentation.

Comment: No. `$('div').remove('#' + stuff)` says to first select all div elements on the page, then remove the one(s) that match the `'#' + stuff` selector. Using `$('#' + stuff).remove()` is both simpler and faster, because it says to first select just the element matching that id and then remove it.

Comment: @DavidThomas Oops you were right, I didn't define a namespace. I'll post a more specific problem later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than Google Chrome not working here, what's happening is that Firefox is *overlooking* your undefined `Location` namespace for some reason. Make sure you've defined it and your functions belong to it, or just use your functions this way (which seems more appropiate for your situation):

```
function removeMe(data) { ... }
function addMe() { ... }
```

And in the [`onclick` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html) of your links, `onclick="removeMe('remove19p'); return false;"` and `onclick="addMe(); return false;"` respectively.

Comment: It seems that FF already has a `Location` object, though I don't know what it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Bu33n/13/ (I do know about `location` (lowercase "l") but not `Location`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn That is strange. I knew about `window.location` but no `Location`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried googling it, but kept just getting results about the lowercase version.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a new Object to Location for it to work in Chrome

```
Location = new Object();
```

Comment: What is the (apparently preexisting) `Location` object in FF? (I know about `location` with a lowercase "l", but not the uppercase "L" version.)

Comment: There may not be a pre-existing object, it may just be that FF checked to see if it could find an object(Location), and when it didn't find it instantiated it auto-magically.

Comment: There is a `Location` object in FF: http://jsfiddle.net/Bu33n/13/ - it doesn't automatically create objects just because they're referenced (why would it?).

Comment: Looks like Location is a DOMPrototype and window.location is of type Location in FF. I didnt find any website with it. Although, I tried this code `({}).toString.call(window.location)` and `({}).toString.call(Location)` in FF.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
    function removeMe(data) {
        $('div').remove('#' + data);
        return false;
    };
    function addMe() {
        $('.container').append("<div class='phoneSet' id='remove19p'>" +
            "<p>I am a replacement phone19</p>" +
            "</div>");
    }
```

AND HTML :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeMe('remove19p');">Remove me</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addMe();">Add me</a>
```

Comment: Note that this wouldn't work if you simply plugged it directly into the OP's fiddle, because the functions would be local to the document ready handler and not accessible from inline `onclick` attributes.