# Jquery remove function follow up

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I submitted this question last week:

[chrome not working with jquery remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026985/chrome-not-working-with-jquery-remove/18027107)

and was able to resolve it (stupidity on my part really), however my example was very simple. Currently I'm trying to use `.remove` to eliminate a complete div from a page before sending an array of inputs to an ajax function. However, I am not able to get `.remove` to work at all.

Here's my latest try:
http://jsfiddle.net/CJ2r9/2/

I get function not defined on the jsfiddle on multiple browsers. On my application I get absolutely no errors, but nothing works either.

I'm relatively new to javascript scopes, so if the problem is scope-wise then please let me know how I'm screwing up.

I have also tried using the `.on` jquery function, but it's a bit more confusing considering my div ids are dynamically loaded from the server (jstl, spring MVC, etc). If that's a solution please let me know how I can get on the right track.

Thank you!

Comment: Change the jsFiddle setting from "onDomready" to "no wrap". The other problem is that the elements you want to remove don't exist. The div elements have IDs like "removeXXX **p**" and in your event handlers you pass "removeXXX **s**". `.on` would be less painful. You don't need IDs in order to remove an element, any reference to it is fine. Bind the event handlers with `.on` and use DOM traversal to find the right element to remove.

Comment: None of the elements you want to remove are in your markup

Comment: Yes thank you for pointing that out. Some phoneSets and scheduleSets were missing ids. I went back and fixed it, but no removal was being done. I went with @FelixKling answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two problems in your jsFiddle are:

- Scope: `removeElem` is not in global scope, since you left the default configuration option to execute the code on DOM ready. You can change it to "no wrap" to make the funciton global.
- The elements you want to remove don't exist. The div elements have IDs like "removeXXXp" and in your event handlers you pass "removeXXXs".

---

Here is an other, simpler solution (in my opinion) for element removal. Given your markup:

```
<div class="scheduleSet" id="remove315p">
    <!-- ... -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="optionHide">Remove</a>
</div>
```

You can use `.on` like so:

```
$('.schduleSet a.optionHide').on('click', function() {
    // traverses up the DOM tree and finds the enclosing .schduleSet element
    $(this).closest('.scheduleSet').remove();
});
```

You don't even need IDs at all.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are already using jquery. Why dont you do it this way:

```
<div id="foo">This needs to be removed</div>
<a href="#" id="remove" data-remove="foo">Remove</a>

function removeElem(element){
    $('#'+element).remove();
}

$(function(){
    $("#remove").click(function(){
        removeElem($(this).data('remove'));
    });
})
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vLgpk/

They way this works is, using `data-remove` (can be anything like data-xyz btw), binds the remove link with the div. You can then read this binding later when remove is clicked.

If you are new to jQuery, and wondering what `data-remove` is, its just custom attribute that you can add to you code which can be later retrieved using the `data()` call on the element. Many great frameworks like Bootstrap use this approach.

Advantage of using this approach in my opinion is you can have the remove links anywhere in your UI and they don't need to be related structurally to your divs by siting inside them.

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple fiddle, the inline `onclick` doesn't see the function defined in javascript so I get a `ReferenceError: myRemove is not defined`.

By adding the listener in js, `.remove()` works fine.

Sorry I don't know what causes the difference in behavior though.

Test it out: http://jsfiddle.net/xTv5M/1/

```
// HTML5
<div id="removeme">foo bar</div>
<button onclick="myRemove('removeme')">Go</button><br>
<div id="removeMe2">foo bar</div>
<button id="go2">Go Again</button>

// js
function myRemove(name){
    $('#'+name).remove()
};

$('#go2').click(function(){ myRemove('removeMe2') });
```